# Unable to find the required index

Tags: java, algorithm

It was an interview question and I was asked to fix the code-->

Given a sorted array, I have to find the array index of the element if it is present, else I have to return -1. Following is my code:

```
public static int returnIndex(int[] a, int x) {
    int n = a.length;
    if (n == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int l = 0;
    int r = n - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;
        if (a[m] > x) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else {
            l = m;
        }
    }
    if (a[l] == x) {
        return l;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Code works fine if I have to find the middle element but fails (goes into infinite loop) when I have to find any other element. Can anyone point out the mistake?

I am allowed to make only **3 modifications** in this code.
Worst case Time Complexity-O(log(n))
Worst case Space Complexity-O(1)

Comment: Hint: You need to handle even length and odd length cases saprately

Comment: One mistake I found is (l=m+1) instead of l=m, but I am still getting error..

Comment: Can you make the loop from the 1st element to the last? From a[0] to a[a.length-1]?

Comment: If it goes into infinate loop, then the condition to break is never met. As I see it, l is always decreased.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying binary search here. So you need to have 3 conditions. midValue > key, midValue < key and midValue == key. You are handling only 2. Also when midValue >  key you need to add one to index. So modify your method like

```
public static int returnIndex(int[] a, int x) {
    int n = a.length;
    if (n == 0) {
        return -1;
    }
    int l = 0;
    int r = n - 1;
    while (l < r) {
        int m = (l + r) / 2;

        if (a[m] > x) {
            r = m - 1;
        } else if(a[m] < x){
            l = m + 1;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

If you are not doing it for an exercise you could achieve the same via `Arrays.binarySearch()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I would it this way:

```
    public static int returnIndex(int[] a, int x) {
        int n = a.length;
        if (n == 0) {
            return -1;
        }
        int l = 0;
        int r = n - 1;
        while (l < r) {
            int m = (l + r) / 2;
            if (a[m] == x) {
                return m;
            }
            if (a[m] > x) {
                r = m - 1;
            } else {
                l = m + 1;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```